# Struts2 redirecting urls having hash

Tags: java, facebook, url, redirect, struts2

I am currently implement a facebook login in my application, after the user has successfully  authorized his or hers account, it would go back to an action class in my web server and on that.

Here's an example

1)User clicks logged in with facebook
2)He or she will be redirected to this facebook authorization page
2) Once he or she has been authorized.the page will then be redirected to struts2 action class.
so the url will be looked like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp-Facebook/oAuthExchange?code=SomeLongFacebookCodHere#_=_
```

if you will see the ending url of oAuthExchange has a `#_=_`.
and then it will be redirected to the dashboard page of my app the page url will looked like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2-Facebook/dashboard#_=_
```

if you'll notice there is a `"#_=_"` in my URL. is there anyway I can remove the `"#_=_"` when I do a redirect?

I am also using [Facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html) for facebook graph API

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it directly from the result page in HTML5 compliant Browsers with `history.pushState()`.

Assuming `#_=_` is fixed (otherwise you need to perform a dynamic `substring` with `indexOf` looking for `#`),
put this in your page:

```
<script>
    //4 is the lenght of #_=_
    var cleanLocation = location.href.substring(0, location.href - 4); 
    history.pushState("","", cleanLocation);
</script>
```

Comment: what if Javascript is disabled?

Comment: The same of a user with an old browser: the URL remains "dirty". Not a big problem btw (if it works the same and it's all about the eye-candy)... paranoids surfing with javascript disabled are used to worst things than an URL not completely pretty ;)